# A special limit for producting of eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

Let (k>0) $A_{k},A$ be complex matrices with size $n\times n$ such that $\lim_{k}A_{k}=A$. Let 
$f$ be a function that $f(A)=r_{1}^{m_{1}}...r_{t}^{m_{t}}$ where $r_i$'s are eigenvalues of $A$ and $ m_{i} $'s are algebraic multiplicities of $r_i$'s.

Then we want to prove $\lim_{k}f(A_{k})=f(A )$. How?

Answer (score 2):

Product of eigenvalues of a square matrix equals determinant of that matrix, so that $f$ is continuous. Apply some theorem you know about limit of continuous functions.

Comment: Is it true that $f(AB)=f(A)f(B)$ for all matrices?

Comment: I already stated $f(A)=\det(A)$.